# How to check if a hook is hooked or not?

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

For example:

```
if ( is_hooked('hook_name') ) {
  throw new \Exception('You cannot hook to a protected action.');
} else {
  do_action('hook_name');
}
```

Is there a way to define the `is_hooked()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, that's called [`has_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_action), which is an alias of [`has_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_filter/). Usage:

```
if ( has_action('hook_name') ) {
  throw new \Exception('You cannot hook to a protected action.');
} else {
  do_action('hook_name');
}
```

These two functions access the global array [`$wp_filter`](https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/debug-wordpress-hooks/) that stores all of the filters / actions